# Transition metals have a half filled s band in their metallic states

Tags: electronic-configuration

I was reading this "[Chemical bonding at surfaces and interfaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ks4678P1vpoC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=half+filled+s+bands+transition+metals&source=bl&ots=xppc4y2KaJ&sig=Z8z3QyMtMd16zRspZcU5UNs4f2I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig4eS-7tLMAhVBNSYKHZnLBFgQ6AEIMzAI#v=onepage&q=half%20filled%20s%20bands%20transition%20metals&f=false)" book. Here in page 69, they argued that interactions of transition metals to s band of adsorbate would be same because transition metals have half filled s band at their metallic state. My confusion is in electronic arrangement of transition metals I am seeing $s^2$ except for atoms having $d^5$ or $d^{10}$. Even $d^{10}$ is actually d block metals not transition metals. What could be the possible explanation of this line?

[image]